# http request to download a file in java

Tags: java, http, cookies, download

Im really new to Java so i hope you can help me.
I want to Programm a http request to download a File (pdf) from a Website. 
The Website is using cookies. So i have to send a first request to get a cookie and then a second to download the file.

I want to use no external Libraries if possible.

This is what i gotso far:

```
URLConnection request = null;
    String url = str;
    CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager(null, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL));
    request = new URL(url ).openConnection();

    System.setProperty("http.maxRedirects", "100");

    InputStream in = request.getInputStream();
    File downloadedFile = File.createTempFile("test", ".pdf");
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(downloadedFile);        
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int len = in.read(buffer);
    while (len != -1) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, len);
        len = in.read(buffer);
        if (Thread.interrupted()) {
            try {
                throw new InterruptedException();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    in.close();
    out.close();
    return downloadedFile.getAbsolutePath();
```

my code seems to do nothing...

Best whishes M1K

Comment: In your question you've said you need to have a cookie before you can download the files, but the code that you've posted resets the `CookieManager` before it connects to download the file which means that all the cookies saved previously will be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using spring framework in your application, See if you can use copy of method of FileCopyUtils  and copy fileInputStream to response outputstream like below.

FileCopyUtils.copy(new FileInputStream(file),                       response.getOutputStream());

Comment: I don' think im using spring framework... I trying this in eclipse. !?

Comment: File downloadedFile = File.createTempFile("test", ".pdf");
if (null != downloadedFile) {
    
    String mimeType = new MimetypesFileTypeMap()
      .getContentType(downloadedFile);
    response.setContentType(mimeType);
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
      "attachment; filename=" + downloadedFile.getName());
    FileCopyUtils.copy(new FileInputStream(downloadedFile),  response.getOutputStream());
   
   }

response is your http response object.

Comment: Sorry. dont really know what to do... ;)
Just trying this in eclipse....
I just want to use no external libraries for this... ;)

Comment: public static int copy(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
  Assert.notNull(in, "No InputStream specified");
  Assert.notNull(out, "No OutputStream specified");
  try {
   int byteCount = 0;
   byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
   int bytesRead = -1;
   while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    byteCount += bytesRead;
   }
   out.flush();
   return byteCount;
  }
  finally {
   try {
    in.close();
   }
   catch (IOException ex) {
   }
   try {
    out.close();
   }
   catch (IOException ex) {
   }
  }
 }

Comment: try implementing and calling that method in your class

Comment: The OP wants to download the pdf file from the URL not to uploaded it. The way he does that is correct, probably the problem is with the cookie. @M1K

Comment: Hey Titus! 
Do you have any Idea whats going wrong with the cookie?